# Trying to draw lines in my form created dynamically, the lines a regather drawn on the main form.. what should I do?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, custom-painting

I am Using Netbeans .. I am trying to create an invoice application.So i created and invoice jframe form on the first .. This form accepts all the invoice details in a tabular manner and i have overridden the paint method to draw some lines in the Invoice jframe.

Now i have dynamically created another Old Items jframe from which gets created when we click a Button. This Forms accepts the details of old products that are being returned. I want to draw some lines in the OldItems jFrame .. But when i try doing so the either the lines get drawn in the main Invoice form or they don't get drawn at all.

Is there any way where i can call a different paint method for different forms?
Here is the code:

```
public class Inovice2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    JLabel lblSno ;
            JLabel lblSn1 ;
            JLabel lblSn2 ;[enter image description here][1]
            JLabel lblSn3 ;
            JLabel lblSn4 ;
            JLabel lblSn5 ;
            JLabel lblSn6 ;
            JLabel lblSn7 ;
            JLabel lblSn8 ;
            JLabel lblSn9 ;
            JLabel lblSn10 ;
            JLabel lblItemType ;
            JLabel lblDesc ;
            JLabel lblPurity;
            JLabel lblGrsWgt1;
            JLabel lblGrsWgt2;
            JLabel lblNetWgt1;
            JLabel lblNetWgt2;
            JLabel lblRate1 ;
            JLabel lblRate2 ;
            JLabel lblLbrTyp1 ;
            JLabel lblLbrTyp2 ;
            JLabel lblLbrChrgs1;
            JLabel lblLbrChrgs2;
            JLabel lblNoOfPcs1;
            JLabel lblNoOfPcs2;
            JLabel lblStoneChrgs1 ;
            JLabel lblStoneChrgs2 ;
            JLabel lblAmt1;
            JLabel lblAmt2;
            int iTransid;
            int iOldFlag =0;
            int iPaintFlag =0;
            JFrame frmOldItemInvoice = new JFrame();


    public Inovice2() {
        initComponents();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
        Date date = new Date();
        txtDate.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
        //System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));


        try{
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PJ","root","root")) {
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select Cust_name from CUSTOMER_DEtaILS");
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    drpdwnCustName.addItem(rs.getString(1));
                }}
       }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){System.out.println(e);}
            this.setLayout(null);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            final Container cn = getContentPane();
            cn.setLayout(null);
            lblSno = new JLabel();
            lblSno.setText("S.No.");
            lblSn1 = new JLabel();
            lblSn1.setText("1");
            lblSn2 = new JLabel();
            lblSn2.setText("2");
            lblSn3 = new JLabel();
            lblSn3.setText("3");
                lblSn4 = new JLabel();
            lblSn4.setText("4");
            lblSn5 = new JLabel();
            lblSn5.setText("5");
            lblSn6 = new JLabel();
            lblSn6.setText("6");
            lblSn7 = new JLabel();
            lblSn7.setText("7");
            lblSn8 = new JLabel();
            lblSn8.setText("8");
            lblSn9 = new JLabel();
            lblSn9.setText("9");
            lblSn10 = new JLabel();
            lblSn10.setText("10");
            lblItemType = new JLabel();
            lblItemType.setText("Item Type");
            lblDesc = new JLabel();
            lblDesc.setText("Description");
            lblPurity = new JLabel();
            lblPurity.setText("Purity");
            lblGrsWgt1 = new JLabel();
            lblGrsWgt1.setText("Gross Wgt");
            lblGrsWgt2 = new JLabel();
            lblGrsWgt2.setText("(In Gms)");
            lblNetWgt1 = new JLabel();
            lblNetWgt1.setText("Net Wgt");
            lblNetWgt2 = new JLabel();
            lblNetWgt2.setText("(In Gms)");
            lblRate1 = new JLabel();
            lblRate1.setText("Rate");
            lblRate2 = new JLabel();
            lblRate2.setText("(Per gm)");
            lblLbrTyp1 = new JLabel();
            lblLbrTyp1.setText("Labour Type");
            lblLbrChrgs1 = new JLabel();
            lblLbrChrgs1.setText("Labour");
            lblLbrChrgs2 = new JLabel();
            lblLbrChrgs2.setText("Charges");
            lblNoOfPcs1= new JLabel();
            lblNoOfPcs1.setText("No. Of");
            lblNoOfPcs2= new JLabel();
            lblNoOfPcs2.setText("Pieces");
            lblStoneChrgs1 = new JLabel();
            lblStoneChrgs1.setText("Stone &");
            lblStoneChrgs2 = new JLabel();
            lblStoneChrgs2.setText("Other Charges");
            lblAmt1 = new JLabel();
            lblAmt1.setText("Amount");
            lblAmt2 = new JLabel();
            lblAmt2.setText("(In Rs.)");
            lblSn1.setBounds(30, 180, 20, 20);
            lblSn2.setBounds(30, 205, 20, 20);
            lblSn3.setBounds(30, 230, 20, 20);
            lblSn4.setBounds(30, 255, 20, 20);
            lblSn5.setBounds(30, 280, 20, 20);
            lblSn6.setBounds(30, 305, 20, 20);
            lblSn7.setBounds(30, 330, 20, 20);
            lblSn8.setBounds(30, 355, 20, 20);
            lblSn9.setBounds(30, 380, 20, 20);
            lblSn10.setBounds(26,405, 20, 20);
            lblSno.setBounds(19, 140, 30, 20);
            lblItemType.setBounds(68, 140, 100, 20);
            lblDesc.setBounds(225, 140, 100, 20);
            lblPurity.setBounds(397, 140, 100, 20);
            lblGrsWgt1.setBounds(470, 140, 100, 20);
            lblGrsWgt2.setBounds(472, 155, 100, 20);
            lblNetWgt1.setBounds(559, 140, 100, 20);
            lblNetWgt2.setBounds(558, 155, 100, 20);
            lblRate1.setBounds(645, 140, 80, 20);
            lblRate2.setBounds(635, 155, 80, 20);
            lblLbrTyp1.setBounds(720, 140, 100, 20);
            lblLbrChrgs1.setBounds(842, 140, 100, 20);
            lblLbrChrgs2.setBounds(838, 155, 100, 20);
            lblNoOfPcs1.setBounds(935, 140, 100, 20);
            lblNoOfPcs2.setBounds(936, 155, 100, 20);
            lblStoneChrgs1.setBounds(1060, 140, 150, 20);
            lblStoneChrgs2.setBounds(1040, 155, 150, 20);
            lblAmt1.setBounds(1190, 140, 850, 20);
            lblAmt2.setBounds(1192, 155, 850, 20);


            cn.add(lblSn1);
            cn.add(lblSn2);
            cn.add(lblSn3);
            cn.add(lblSn4);
            cn.add(lblSn5);
            cn.add(lblSn6);
            cn.add(lblSn7);
            cn.add(lblSn8);
            cn.add(lblSn9);
            cn.add(lblSn10);
            cn.add(lblSno);
            cn.add(lblItemType);
            cn.add(lblDesc);
            cn.add(lblPurity);
            cn.add(lblGrsWgt1);
            cn.add(lblGrsWgt2);
            cn.add(lblNetWgt1);
            cn.add(lblNetWgt2);
            cn.add(lblRate1);
            cn.add(lblRate2);
            cn.add(lblLbrTyp1);
            cn.add(lblLbrChrgs1);
            cn.add(lblLbrChrgs2);
            cn.add(lblNoOfPcs1);
            cn.add(lblNoOfPcs2);
            cn.add(lblStoneChrgs1);
            cn.add(lblStoneChrgs2);
            cn.add(lblAmt1);
            cn.add(lblAmt2);


        setSize(1300,1300);
        this.repaint();

    }

     @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        if (iPaintFlag == 0)
        {

              // fixes the immediate problem.
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                Line2D hlin0 = new Line2D.Float(15, 160, 1275, 160);
                g2.draw(hlin0);
                Line2D hlin1 = new Line2D.Float(15, 200, 1275, 200);
                g2.draw(hlin1);
                Line2D hlin2 = new Line2D.Float(15, 225, 1275, 225);
                g2.draw(hlin2);
                Line2D hlin3 = new Line2D.Float(15, 250, 1275, 250);
                g2.draw(hlin3);
                Line2D hlin4 = new Line2D.Float(15, 275, 1275, 275);
                g2.draw(hlin4);
                Line2D hlin5 = new Line2D.Float(15, 300, 1275, 300);
                g2.draw(hlin5);
                Line2D hlin6 = new Line2D.Float(15, 325, 1275, 325);
                g2.draw(hlin6);
                Line2D hlin7 = new Line2D.Float(15, 350, 1275, 350);
                g2.draw(hlin7);
                Line2D hlin8 = new Line2D.Float(15, 375, 1275, 375);
                g2.draw(hlin8);
                Line2D hlin9 = new Line2D.Float(15, 400, 1275, 400);
                g2.draw(hlin9);
                Line2D hlin10 = new Line2D.Float(15, 425, 1275, 425);
                g2.draw(hlin10);
                Line2D hlin11 = new Line2D.Float(15, 450, 1275, 450);
                g2.draw(hlin11);
                Line2D hlin12 = new Line2D.Float(15, 475, 1275, 475);
                g2.draw(hlin12);
                Line2D hlin13 = new Line2D.Float(1000, 527, 1275, 527);
                g2.draw(hlin13);
                Line2D hlin14 = new Line2D.Float(1000, 602, 1275, 602);
                g2.draw(hlin14);
                Line2D hlin15 = new Line2D.Float(1000, 627, 1275, 627);
                g2.draw(hlin15);
                Line2D hlin16 = new Line2D.Float(1000, 652, 1275, 652);
                g2.draw(hlin16);

                Line2D vlin0 = new Line2D.Float(15, 160, 15, 475);
                g2.draw(vlin0);
                Line2D vlin1 = new Line2D.Float(50, 160, 50, 475);
                g2.draw(vlin1);
                Line2D vlin2 = new Line2D.Float(150, 160, 150, 475);
                g2.draw(vlin2);
                Line2D vlin3 = new Line2D.Float(370, 160, 370, 475);
                g2.draw(vlin3);
                Line2D vlin4 = new Line2D.Float(460, 160, 460, 475);
                g2.draw(vlin4);
                Line2D vlin5 = new Line2D.Float(540, 160, 540, 475);
                g2.draw(vlin5);
                Line2D vlin6 = new Line2D.Float(620, 160, 620, 475);
                g2.draw(vlin6);
                Line2D vlin7 = new Line2D.Float(700, 160, 700, 475);
                g2.draw(vlin7);
                Line2D vlin8 = new Line2D.Float(812, 160, 812, 475);
                g2.draw(vlin8);
                Line2D vlin9 = new Line2D.Float(912, 160, 912, 475);
                g2.draw(vlin9);
                Line2D vlin10 = new Line2D.Float(1000, 160, 1000, 652);
                g2.draw(vlin10);
                Line2D vlin11 = new Line2D.Float(1170, 160, 1170, 652);
                g2.draw(vlin11);
                Line2D vlin12 = new Line2D.Float(1275, 160, 1275, 652);
                g2.draw(vlin12);

        }
        else

        {
              Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Line2D hlin0 = new Line2D.Float(90, 140, 880, 140);
            g2.draw(hlin0);
            Line2D hlin1 = new Line2D.Float(90, 170, 880, 170);
            g2.draw(hlin1);
            Line2D hlin2 = new Line2D.Float(90, 195, 880, 195);
            g2.draw(hlin2);
            Line2D hlin3 = new Line2D.Float(90, 220, 880, 220);
            g2.draw(hlin3);
            Line2D hlin4 = new Line2D.Float(90, 245, 880, 245);
            g2.draw(hlin4);
            Line2D hlin5 = new Line2D.Float(90, 270, 880, 270);
            g2.draw(hlin5);
            Line2D hlin6 = new Line2D.Float(90, 295, 880, 295);
            g2.draw(hlin6);
            Line2D hlin7 = new Line2D.Float(90, 320, 880, 320);
            g2.draw(hlin7);
            Line2D hlin8 = new Line2D.Float(90, 345, 880, 345);
            g2.draw(hlin8);
            Line2D hlin9 = new Line2D.Float(90, 370, 880, 370);
            g2.draw(hlin9);
            Line2D hlin10 = new Line2D.Float(90, 395, 880, 395);
            g2.draw(hlin10);
            Line2D hlin11 = new Line2D.Float(90, 420, 880, 420);
            g2.draw(hlin11);
            Line2D hlin12 = new Line2D.Float(660, 445, 880, 445);
            g2.draw(hlin12);
            Line2D vlin0 = new Line2D.Float(90, 140, 90, 420);
            g2.draw(vlin0);
            Line2D vlin1 = new Line2D.Float(140, 140, 140, 420);
            g2.draw(vlin1);
            Line2D vlin2 = new Line2D.Float(240, 140, 240, 420);
            g2.draw(vlin2);
            Line2D vlin3 = new Line2D.Float(440, 140, 440, 420);
            g2.draw(vlin3);
            Line2D vlin4 = new Line2D.Float(540, 140, 540, 420);
            g2.draw(vlin4);
            Line2D vlin5 = new Line2D.Float(660, 140, 660, 445);
            g2.draw(vlin5);
            Line2D vlin6 = new Line2D.Float(760, 140, 760, 445);
            g2.draw(vlin6);
            Line2D vlin7 = new Line2D.Float(880, 140, 880, 445);
            g2.draw(vlin7);

        }
  }


    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        txtDate = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnCal = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnAddOld = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lblCustName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        drpdwnCustName = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        lblDate = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnCal.setText("<>");
        btnCal.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCalActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("SALE INVOICE");

        btnAddOld.setText("Old Jewellery Purchase");
        btnAddOld.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAddOldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblCustName.setText("Customer Name");

        drpdwnCustName.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "---Select---" }));

        lblDate.setText("Date");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblCustName)
                        .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                        .addComponent(drpdwnCustName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                        .addComponent(lblDate)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(txtDate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 202, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                        .addComponent(btnCal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                        .addComponent(btnAddOld, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 185, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(341, 341, 341)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                .addContainerGap(307, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblCustName)
                    .addComponent(drpdwnCustName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lblDate)
                    .addComponent(txtDate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnCal)
                    .addComponent(btnAddOld))
                .addContainerGap(428, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnCalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        txtDate.setText(new pj.Calendar().setPickedDate());
    }                                      

    private void btnAddOldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        //String str[]={"1","2"};
        //pj.OldItemInvoice.main(str);

        iPaintFlag=1;

        frmOldItemInvoice.setSize(600, 700);
        JLabel lblOldSno ;
        JLabel lblOldSn1 ;
        JLabel lblOldSn2 ;
        JLabel lblOldSn3 ;
        JLabel lblOldSn4 ;
        JLabel lblOldSn5 ;
        JLabel lblOldSn6 ;
        JLabel lblOldSn7 ;
        JLabel lblOldSn8 ;
        JLabel lblOldSn9 ;
        JLabel lblOldSn10 ;
        JLabel lblOldItemType ;
        JLabel lblOldDesc ;
        JLabel lblOldPurity;
        JLabel lblOldWgt;
        JLabel lblOldRate ;
        JLabel lblOldAmt;
        JLabel lblOldTtlAmt;
        JLabel OldTtlAmt;
        JLabel lblNoOfOldItems;



        frmOldItemInvoice.setLayout(null);

        lblNoOfOldItems = new JLabel();
        lblNoOfOldItems.setText("No. Of Old Items");
        lblNoOfOldItems.setBounds(350, 50, 125, 25);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblNoOfOldItems);
        lblOldSno = new JLabel();
        lblOldSno.setText("S.No.");
        lblOldSn1 = new JLabel();
        lblOldSn1.setText("1");
        lblOldSn2 = new JLabel();
        lblOldSn2.setText("2");
        lblOldSn3 = new JLabel();
        lblOldSn3.setText("3");
        lblOldSn4 = new JLabel();
        lblOldSn4.setText("4");
        lblOldSn5 = new JLabel();
        lblOldSn5.setText("5");
        lblOldSn6 = new JLabel();
        lblOldSn6.setText("6");
        lblOldSn7 = new JLabel();
        lblOldSn7.setText("7");
        lblOldSn8 = new JLabel();
        lblOldSn8.setText("8");
        lblOldSn9 = new JLabel();
        lblOldSn9.setText("9");
        lblOldSn10 = new JLabel();
        lblOldSn10.setText("10");
        lblOldItemType = new JLabel();
        lblOldItemType.setText("Item Type");
        lblOldDesc = new JLabel();
        lblOldDesc.setText("Description");
        lblOldPurity = new JLabel();
        lblOldPurity.setText("Purity (%)");
        lblOldWgt = new JLabel();
        lblOldWgt.setText("Weight (In Gms)");
        lblOldRate = new JLabel();
        lblOldRate.setText("Rate (Per Gm)");
        lblOldAmt = new JLabel();
        lblOldAmt.setText("Amount (In Rs. )");
        lblOldSn1.setBounds(110, 155, 20, 20);
        lblOldSn2.setBounds(110, 180, 20, 20);
        lblOldSn3.setBounds(110, 205, 20, 20);
        lblOldSn4.setBounds(110, 230, 20, 20);
        lblOldSn5.setBounds(110, 255, 20, 20);
        lblOldSn6.setBounds(110, 280, 20, 20);
        lblOldSn7.setBounds(110, 305, 20, 20);
        lblOldSn8.setBounds(110, 330, 20, 20);
        lblOldSn9.setBounds(110, 355, 20, 20);
        lblOldSn10.setBounds(106, 380, 20, 20);
        lblOldSno.setBounds(100, 125, 30, 20);
        lblOldItemType.setBounds(150, 125, 100, 20);
        lblOldDesc.setBounds(250, 125, 100, 20);
        lblOldPurity.setBounds(450, 125, 100, 20);
        lblOldWgt.setBounds(550, 125, 100, 20);
        lblOldRate.setBounds(670, 125, 100, 20);
        lblOldAmt.setBounds(770, 125, 100, 20);

        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSn1);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSn2);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSn3);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSn4);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSn5);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSn6);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSn7);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSn8);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSn9);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSn10);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldSno);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldItemType);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldDesc);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldPurity);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldWgt);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldRate);
        frmOldItemInvoice.add(lblOldAmt);

        frmOldItemInvoice.setSize(1000,550);
        frmOldItemInvoice.setVisible(true);
        frmOldItemInvoice.repaint();

    }                                         

}
```

Desired result

[image]

Actual result

[image]

these are the output windows .. i want lines in the second screenshot .

Comment: It's only your `Invoice2` class that has a `paint()` method, so all drawing is on this frame. If you want to draw on the `frmOldItemInvoice` you need a `paint()` method for that class too.

Comment: That appears to be 'mostly tabular' data, so I'd be tempted to use a `JTable`. Why is row 11 completely blank? What is the significance of the last 4 rows that are aligned with the last two columns? As general advice: for better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).